# I can't update wine from 1.5.10 to 1.5.11 due to a dpkg lock file

Tags: dpkg

I have tried double checking for updates and updating the ppa via the terminal. The terminal outputs this, at the end.

```
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

Any ideas?
Thank you.

Comment: Were you running the update manager, or any other update software. If so, wait until, it is done and then try again.

Comment: If above comment was not the problem , then look at my answer .

Answer (score 1):

open your terminal and type this

```
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

then try again .
hope that helps .

Comment: Thanks the error went away, but I still can't get wine to update. According to winehq it was released two days ago.

Comment: Hi if its released then its will be with your next ubuntu updates . try to update your system .